# Displaying images in WP8 from facebook RSS feed, C#, XAML

Tags: c#, facebook, xaml, windows-phone-8, rss

I have one little, simple question.

Im building app where i want show news from facebook page. Im parsing facebook rss feed into my lists and then im binding that lists into my custom listbox.

Description is ok, but there is problem with images. I get link like this:

```
<img class="img" src="https://scontent-a-ams.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/p130x130/10848057_839932902696038_5734460437725129145_n.jpg?oh=5ba54764221f619e879266d27caa797e&amp;oe=55180DA4" alt="">
```

I am taking "src" from this html and bind it into `<Image>` in xaml, but i cant see anything. No images are there.

If you would copy this link into web browser you will get just error.

Anybody idea how to resolve this?

I will be thankful, Grow#.

Comment: Anybody, please... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of HTML special char '&' in URL is transformed into '&'. Change:

```
https://scontent-a-ams.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/p130x130/10848057_839932902696038_5734460437725129145_n.jpg?oh=5ba54764221f619e879266d27caa797e&amp;oe=55180DA4
```

to:

```
https://scontent-a-ams.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/p130x130/10848057_839932902696038_5734460437725129145_n.jpg?oh=5ba54764221f619e879266d27caa797e&oe=55180DA4
```